# Basis for $\mathbb R^{n\times m}$ using $n$ linearly independent $n$-vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Exhibit a basis set for $\mathbb R ^{n\times m}$ for $n\geq m$.

Obviously
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&...&0\\0&0&...&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&...&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&1&...&0\\0&0&...&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&...&0\end{pmatrix},...,\begin{pmatrix}0&0&...&0\\0&0&...&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&...&1\end{pmatrix}$$
is a basis. But the text says

> If $n\ge m$, **a set of $nm$ $n\times m$ matrices whose columns consist of all combinations of a set of $n$ n-vectors that span $\mathbb R^n$ is a basis set for** $\mathbb R^{n\times m}$. If $n<m$ we can likewise form a basis set for $\mathbb R^{n\times m}$ or for subspaces for $\mathbb R^{n\times m}$ in a similar way.

What does this confusing language mean? Surely my answer works, but it sounds like they're trying something fancy with something not just $1$'s and $0$'s, but I can't understand it.

So say we have n linearly independent n-vectors. We would need to have $nm$ total matrices. I'm not sure what the boldfaced means. For example, we have $n$ linearly independent vectors $v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n$. Some combinations are be $(v_1,v_1,...,v_1),(v_2,v_2,...,v_2),\cdots,(v_n,v_n,...,v_n)$, we need some more to get $nm$. Not sure what the boldface means.

Answer (score 1):

I think it just means that if $\textbf v_1,\textbf v_2,...,\textbf v_n$ is a basis for $\mathbb R^n$, a basis for $\mathbb R^{n\times m}$ can be

$$(\textbf v_1,0,...,0),(\textbf v_2,0,...,0),...,(\textbf v_n,0,...,0),...,(0,0,...,\textbf v_n)$$

In particular the basis in my question used the unit vectors $\textbf v_1=\textbf e_1,...,\textbf v_n=\textbf e_n$

Answer (score 0):

The basis set you wrote down in your question is surely a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$. In fact it is the orthonormal basis of this set. But recall that this need not be the only basis for $\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$. In order to find a general basis, you need to start with a general basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

So, you start with a basis $\{e_1,e_2,\cdots,e_n\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, where the $e_i$'s are $n\times1$ column vectors. Now, to construct a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ you need to take distinct combinations of the $e_i$'s as columns of $nm$ $n\times m$ matrices. Since $n\geq m$, this ensures that you would get a complete basis for $\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$.

Comment: Doesn’t seem to work as the matrices could be linearly dependent, thus not span $\mathbb R^{n\times m}$. For example in $\mathbb R^{8\times3}$, $(v_1v_2v_3)=(v_1v_2v_8)+(v_2v_4v_3)-(v_2v_4v_8)$ even though the columns are all distinct combinations. But we need $nm$ linearly independent matrices

Comment: I don't how the problem you indicated is relevant here. In my answer I have clearly stated that we need $nm$ matrices from a linearly independent set. This automatically rules out the above problem you have stated.

Comment: Im saying those 4 are distinct combinations, but are linearly dependent, so taking distinct combinations doesn’t seem to work